# Found a mistake in a proof about when GGH will decrypt incorrectly

Tags: public-key, lattice-crypto, matrix-multiplication

The proof is [here on page 66, lemma 20](http://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?file&key1=35477). I found the same mistake in other sources also.

It claims that GGH decryption will fail only if $\lceil R^{-1}e\rfloor \not =0$. Here $R$ is the "good" private basis for the lattice and $e$ is the small random vector. Rounding symbol means just that every coordinate of the vector will be rounded to the nearest integer.

In the proof they use the "fact" that $B^{-1}R$ is an unimodular matrix. They come to this conclusion from the fact that the two bases are connected by a unimodular matrix $U$ like this

$$B=UR.$$

This is correct. However from this they deduce that $$U^{-1}=B^{-1}R.$$ This is clearly false. Actually $$U^{-1}=RB^{-1}.$$ There is no guarantee that $B^{-1}R$ is unimodular.

Have any of you come across another way to prove this result?

Comment: The original paper writes $T = B^{-1}{R}$, so I think this $U^{-1}$ is a typo on the PDF you linked. Take a look at [Lemma 4, page 7](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/pubs/shafi/1997-lncs-ggh.pdf).  Moreover, $U^{-1}$ is not really used. Therefore, your question may be simplified to "Why is $B^{-1}{R}$ unimodular?"

Comment: $B^{-1}R$ isn't necessarily unimodular. This is the heart of the problem. Let $$R=\begin{Bmatrix}
1& 0 \\
0& 2 
\end{Bmatrix}$$ and 
$$U=\begin{Bmatrix}
1& 0 \\
1& 1
\end{Bmatrix}.$$
$U$ is unimodular, so
$$B=UR=\begin{Bmatrix}
1& 0 \\
1& 2
\end{Bmatrix}.$$
Now
$$R^{-1}B=\begin{Bmatrix}
1& 0 \\
0& \frac{1}{2}
\end{Bmatrix}\begin{Bmatrix}
1& 0 \\
1& 2
\end{Bmatrix}=\begin{Bmatrix}
1& 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}& 1
\end{Bmatrix},$$ which is not unimodular and neither is it's inverse $B^{-1}R$. Hopefully you see what I'm getting at.

Comment: Yes, I had already understood that when I posted my comment. But maybe the original paper chooses $R$ with some extra properties to force this product to be unimodular. It is a good idea to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this was a really stupid mistake by me. I got confused because some sources use notation where $R$ and $B$ have the basis vectors as rows. However Goldreich, Goldwasser and Halevi have the basis vectors as columns so 
$$B=RU\implies U=R^{-1}B.$$ Hence the matrix is unimodular and the proof works. Sorry about the inconvience.